# How to get 2 periods of dates in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I want to subtract 2 periods of dates to compare data of current year vs previous year and my query is not working.

If I remove a period it works, but not sure how to pull 2 periods.

Thanks

```
 SELECT  year(date) as year, WEEK(ADDDATE(date, 5-DAYOFWEEK(date)), 3) AS 'Week', DATE, 
 FROM TABLE
 WHERE year(date) in (2015, 2016)
 AND (DATE BETWEEN "2016-10-23" AND "2016-11-12")
 AND (DATE BETWEEN "2015-11-06" AND "2015-11-12")
 ORDER BY DATE, year(date)
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one.

```
 SELECT  year(date) as year, WEEK(ADDDATE(date, 5-DAYOFWEEK(date)), 3) AS 'Week', DATE, 
 FROM TABLE
 WHERE 
 ((DATE BETWEEN "2016-10-23" AND "2016-11-12")) OR 
 ((DATE BETWEEN "2015-11-06" AND "2015-11-12"))
 ORDER BY DATE, year(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `or`:

```
SELECT year(date) as year, WEEK(ADDDATE(date, 5-DAYOFWEEK(date)), 3) AS Week, DATE
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2016-10-23' AND '2016-11-12' OR
      DATE BETWEEN '2015-11-06' AND '2015-11-12';
```

Notes:

- You don't need the `date()` comparison in the `where` clause.
- You should use single quotes for date and string constants.
- You should not use single quotes for column aliases.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT year(DATE) AS year
,WEEK(ADDDATE(DATE, 5 - DAYOFWEEK(DATE)), 3) AS 'Week'
,DATE
FROM TABLE
WHERE (
    (
        DATE BETWEEN '2016-10-23'
            AND '2016-11-12'
        )
    OR (
        DATE BETWEEN '2015-11-06'
            AND '2015-11-12'
        )
    )
```